# vim-php-cs-fixer does not work by php-cs-fixer ver.2.*

Tags: php, vim

I use vim-php-cs-fixer to fix my php code, and php-cs-fixer is ver.2.9 installed by composer.

If I call PhpCsFixerFixFile(), the error occur.

> You are running PHP CS Fixer with xdebug enabled. This has a major 
>   impact on runtime performance.
>
> If you need help while solving warnings, ask at https://gitter.im/PHP-CS-Fixer, we will help you!
>
> The "--level" option does not exist.
>
> fix [--path-mode PATH-MODE] [--allow-risky ALLOW-RISKY] [--config CONFIG] [--dry-run] [--rules RULES] [--using-cache USING-CACHE] [--cache-file CACHE-FILE] [--diff] [--diff-format DIFF-FORMAT] [--format FORMAT] [--stop-on-violation] [--show-progress SHOW-PROGRESS] [--] []...

I tried to php-cs-fixer ver.1.*, and I succeeded fix file.

But ver.2.*, I failed to fix.

This is my vim-php-cs-fixer settings

```vim
let g:php_cs_fixer_path = "~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer" " define the path to the php-cs-fixer.phar
let g:php_cs_fixer_enable_default_mapping = 1     " Enable the mapping by default (<leader>pcd)
let g:php_cs_fixer_php_path = "php"
let g:php_cs_fixer_rules = "@PSR2"
```

I don't set level option, but level error occur.
why?

Comment: How about using the plugin's issue tracker?